# what causes frequent temporary network outages

Tags: wireless, networking, toshiba-satellite

I use ubuntu 13.04 and fairly often loose the internet connection. Most precisely the connection to the wifi rooter is not lost, I just cannot connect to any website or ping an address. This happens randomly and lasts 30-60 sec then internet works again. A few interesting facts :

- I re installed ubuntu and the problem still happens.
- I installed windows the problem is not happening
- Another machines connecting to the same rooter don't have such issue

I suspect there is a bad combination of my hardware (toshiba Satellite L655) and ubuntu. What may cause this? How do I start troubleshooting it?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: Here is the result : http://pastebin.com/hd5QmZVK   Thanks in advance

Comment: Forgot to mention your name @WildMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

remove:

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

save, close gedit and reboot.

Comment: I did the above steps, but executing 

   sudo modprobe -r wl 

return 
   FATAL: Module wl not found. 

The other issue is that the two lines to be removed  were not in the file. Other than that I did what you suggested. It will take a few days to validate if it helps, so I give an upvote meanwhile, Thanks!

Comment: I changed the name of the file, the brcsmac and bcma driver should be in the file now please remove them. The wl driver should have been gone after running the purge command so it is normal for it to not find the wl driver, I just wanted to make sure it was gone.

Comment: We use the computer for a few days and problem seems to be gone. Just for the sake of curiosity, what were the changes I made?

Comment: We replaced the wl driver the native  brcmsmac driver. And removed brcmsmac and bcma from the blacklist file so they could be used.