# Frequent temporary internet outages

Tags: networking, wireless

Basically my question is about the same problem that is described here: [what causes frequent temporary network outages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341055/what-causes-frequent-temporary-network-outages) - the same 30-60 sec outages every several minutes while NetworkManager doesn't show any signs of lost connection.

I use ubuntu 14.04.4 (can't use 16 due to "clear screen without any panes" bug). JIC I ran the script from the abovementioned post and posted the result here: http://pastebin.com/QjgT7X5Q

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to completely repair this:

1. Go here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported
2. Find your card model and type - maybe just look at the physical device. lspci / lsusb not necessary detect it (e.g. my TP-Link usb adapter was not recognized by Ubuntu)
3. Then go to the corresponding producer page (e.g. for my card - TP-link USB - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link#USB)
4. Find you device model and check whether it "works out of the box". For my device and driver (TL-WN821N Realtek rtl8192cu) value was "No" so I followed instructions in the comments and made in work in a couple of minutes.

Good luck to you if you have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

At your router, change the wireless encryption settings to WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

This change alone should improve the network performance for all devices.